# Justify $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\sin(x)/x|^n\,dx<\infty$ for $n\geq2$

Tags: calculus

I know $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(x)/x\,dx=\pi$. I know the integral is finite, but don't know how to show that it is. Obviously, bounding $\sin(x)<1$ doesn't help. Thanks

Comment: Looks like this converges for $n > 1$ because $\int_1^{\infty} x^{-n} dx$does

Answer (score 2):

*Outline*: The function is nice between $-1$ and $1$, since $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ has limit $1$ as $x\to 0$.

In the interval $[1,\infty)$, the function has absolute value $\le \frac{1}{x^n}$.

In the interval $(-\infty,-1]$ the function has absolute value $\le \frac{1}{|x|^n}$.